# jQuery load(function) for an image file

Tags: jquery, file, load, bandwidth, pagespeed

I'm making a website with lots of background images and (of course) it affects the speed ratio and the bandwidth.

I have a page wich contains 17mb of images data. Most of it is hidden and only appears when you click on target galleries.

The problem is that when the page is loading it downloads every single image even if not displayed at first.

I'd like to make a jQuery request for the browser to load those images only if necessary.

I know how to use the load(function) for a .div but not for an entire file.

The website I'm working on : http://www.adiwatt.com

The page I'm talking about : http://www.adiwatt.com/realisations.html

Many Thanks

Comment: browser doesn't load the image un-till it is displayed in the page it doen't load the media just beacause you added in the dom

Comment: if you are so concern you can use lazyload plugin

Comment: I'll try lazyload. But Chrome console tells me everything is downloaded (see screenshot : http://www.adiwatt.com/loading.png). Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Those images in the screenshot are initially hidden.